# Append a line to previous in Notepad++ with Python script

Tags: python, notepad++

I have a text file which contains lines with tab-indented and not indened. It looks like:

```
A    a1,asdf,lkjhj
     some thing here
B    MORE THINGS,HERE
C    MORE TEXTS HERE
     HERE ALSO TEXTS
     AND SO
```

I want to join indented lines with previous ones.

The result should look like:

```
  A    a1,asdf,lkjhj some thing here
  B    MORE THINGS,HERE
  C    MORE TEXTS HERE  HERE ALSO TEXTS AND SO
```

As the file have more than 22,000 lines I tried to automate with a Python script using the notepad++ module `Npp`. I tried this:

```
import sys
from Npp import *

notepad.open("input.txt")
i= 0

line=editor.gotoLine(i)
if  line.startsWith('^[\t]' ) :
        notepad.runMenuCommand( 'Macro','line join')
else:
pass
i=i+1
print 'done'
Notpad.save()
```

This does not work. How can I fix it?

Comment: Does it not work? In what way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an alternative to using Notepad++, you could just use Python directly to modify the input file:

```
with open('input.txt', 'r') as f_input:
    text = f_input.read()
    text = re.sub(r'(^.*?(?=\n\S+|\Z))', lambda x: re.sub(r"(\n\s+)", " ", x.group(1)), text, flags=re.M+re.S)

with open('input.txt', 'w') as f_output:
    f_output.write(text)
```

This would give you the following output:

```
A    a1,asdf,lkjhj some thing here
B    MORE THINGS,HERE
C    MORE TEXTS HERE HERE ALSO TEXTS AND SO
```